# Restricting origins with Cors and Owin token authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, cors

Ive managed to enable Cors fine and my client application communications to my web API application using AJAX.  The problem is its open to any host now.  I added the following line to Startup.Auth.cs:

```
 app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
```

I was using the standard WebApi method for cors, but had problems when issuing token authentication.

My question is how do i restrict origins using this method?

Comment: In the `ConfigureServices` method you can add the CORS policy like `services.AddCors(options => { options.AddPolicty("NameOfPolicy", builder => bulider.WithOrigins(<<Name of Host>>))});` And later you have to use the same policy name in `app.UseCors` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict the origin using [CorsPolicyBuilder Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.cors.infrastructure.corspolicybuilder?view=aspnetcore-2.0)

```
   app.UseCors(builder =>
        builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost", "https://localhost"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Define one or more named CORS policies, and then select the policy by name at run time

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin",
            builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://example.com"));
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    ...
    // Shows UseCors with named policy.
    app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");
   ...
}
```

You can read how to define CORS at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.1).